# Download file via Dropbox API from browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dropbox

I am writing a simple Chrome extension where I need to upload and download files to dropbox. As mentioned in the [Dropbox File Download API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET), when I download a file via a ajax request, I get the contents of the file which I can log in the browser console. As far as I know it is not possible/feasible to write contents to disk from in-browser javascript, so how can I possibly do that so that the user can `download` the file.

**EDIT:**

```
//Simple function to download a file
function downloadFile(){
    var filePath = $(this).closest('tr').attr('path');
    var url = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/auto"+filePath;
    var headers = {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken()
    };
    var args = {
        url: url,
        headers: headers,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data, textStatus, request)
        {
            var metadata = $.parseJSON(request.getResponseHeader('x-dropbox-metadata'));
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR){
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    };
    $.ajax(args);
}
```

Comment: Do you have your own web server for this?  Probably you should make an ajax call to your server, call the dropbox api, then return from your ajax call with the appropriate mime type, redirecting to it in the web browser to prompt a download.

Comment: Providing your current code will help us help you help us all.

Comment: @Brian and @Xan I have added the simple code I have written reading the documention of dropbox. `console.log(data)` prints the downloaded file contents to console. How do I write it to a file ? or If I could give a download dialogue box to the user that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it, using `chrome.downloads` API:

```
function downloadFile() {
    var filePath = $(this).closest('tr').attr('path');
    var url = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/auto"+filePath;
    var headers = {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken()
    };
    var args = {
        url: url,
        headers: headers,
        method: 'GET', // note the attribut name change
        filename: "FillThisOut" // may not be required
    };
    chrome.downloads.download(args, function(downloadId) {
        /* additional processing of the download, if needed */
    });
}
```